# Accessing the exact data sent using WebClient.UploadData on the server

Tags: asp.net, http, request, webclient

Newbie question: I'm sending a large text string in the form of a byte array using the WebClient.UploadData method to a web site but I'm not sure exactly where to retrieve that data from on the server. I've read posts that say it is in the request object which I already know but how exactly do I retrieve the specific byte array I sent like in the following c# pseudo code:

```
byte[] dataSent = request.GettheByteArrayISentFromWebClientUploadDataMethod;
```

I understand that it may not be as simple as this and that I may need to do some other processing but can anyone post a code snippet that shows how I can get at the byte array that was sent?

Mucho Thank-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading it from the request stream [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx):

```
var bytes = new byte[request.InputStream.Length];
Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

If you are sending key/value pairs then you could use the [UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) method and read them simply as request paraneters:

```
string value = Request["someKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked but it raises a couple of other questions: is there a limit to the amount of data that can be passed using this method and is there a danger of any other data being added to the InputStream as it makes it's way to the server?