# How to read data from WebClient.UploadData

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

First time posting! I've been breaking my head on this particular case. I've got a Web application that needs to upload a file towards a web-api and receive an SVG file (in a string) back.

The web-app uploads the file as follows:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var response = client.UploadFile(apiUrl, FileIGotEarlierInMyCode);

                ViewBag.MessageTest = response.ToString();
            }
```

Above works, but then we get to the API Part:
How do I access the uploaded file? Pseudocode:

```
public string Post([FromBody]File f)
        {
            File uploadedFile = f;

            String svgString = ConvertDataToSVG(uploadedFile);
            return s;
        }
```

In other words: How do I upload/send an XML-file to my Web-api, use/manipulate it there and send other data back?

Thanks in advance!
Nick

PS: I tried this answer:
[Accessing the exact data sent using WebClient.UploadData on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267078/accessing-the-exact-data-sent-using-webclient-uploaddata-on-the-server)
But my code did not compile on Request.InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Request.InputStream didn't work for you is that the *Request* property can refer to *different types of Request objects*, depending on what kind of ASP.NET solution you are developing. There is:

- [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx), as available in Web Forms,
- [HttpRequestBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.aspx), as available in MVC Controllers
- [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), as available in Web API Controllers.

You are using Web API, so HttpRequestMessage it is. Here is how you read the raw request bytes using this class:

```
var data = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```